# Switching from Title bar to Action Bar

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an older android app that has a action bar like so:

[image]

I'm assuming this is the way action bars use to be set up? And if so how do i change it to the more typical one like this:

[image]

I've already tried doing a styles file with the color and set the application to use it but that's not working. I'm hoping this is a typical conversion process that I'm unaware of.

Edit:

manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Style:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

        <!-- Title Bar -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/base_color</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/base_color</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: The first image isn't an `ActionBar`. It is just the title bar

Comment: In facts, you'll need some more effort to get an ActionBar working. To begin, add the support libraries (v4 and v7), if your minSdkVersion is lower than 11.

Comment: Awesome, that's a step in the right direction....

Comment: Have you read the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) developer documentation?

Comment: @Vyger Min sdk is set to 13.

Comment: @Tanis.7x yes but obviously haven't used title bars before

Comment: That's fine- the documentation still outlines how to add the Action Bar to your applications.

Comment: @Tanis.7x the issues isn't how to add the action bar but how to remove the title bar to show the action bar.

Comment: So, you don't even need the support libraries - you're just set to go.

Comment: Do you have your application showing both? As far as I know, that isn't possible using any of the default themes presented in that guide. The action bar will completely replace the title bar. The actual process is as simple as changing the theme that your application uses (perhaps adding the support library or changing your target SDK depending on your requirements and outlined by tyczj below)

Comment: @Tanis.7x " to remove the title bar to show the action bar" where did you get i wanted to show both?

Comment: Your prior comment made it sound as though you knew how to add the action bar, but didn't know how to remove the title bar. I apologies for that misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I do know how to add the action bar and i wanted to remove the title bar that is correct. However your comment made it sound like i wanted both. Anyways, not a problem tyczj below figured out what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first and foremost that is not an actionbar in your first image, that is the titlebar.

To get the `ActionBar` you need to increase your min sdk to > 11 or else use the Support library's AppCompat to get the `SupportActionBar`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

If you are targeting API 13 then you need to adjust your theme to something like this

`<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light" ... >`

Comment: The min sdk is 13... is the option to use the title bar vs the action bar in the manafest or somewhere else?

Comment: you then changed your theme of your app, see my edit

Comment: your theme is the non-holo theme

Comment: Thus you should just need to change `parent="android:Theme.Light"` to `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"`. Be aware that this will change a number of other styles in your application as well.

Comment: I'm not sure where that matters, I've done it like this on previous apps as the image shows, and it work. Please explain

Comment: it worked because that is the correct theme to use the actionbar. the theme you referenced is pre-holo/actionbar aka. old android